# How to fetch max grade for same course in different academic session

Tags: sql, oracle, peoplesoft

I am working on PEOPLESOFT CMS . Students enroll in courses and
    receive grades. Sometimes a student repeats a course and gets a
    better grade. I need to calculate the GPA by using only the best
    grade. So for each student that repeats courses, I have to determine
    what the highest grade is.E.g. in 2nd semester he got 3 grade_point
    but in in 4 semester he improved to 4.5 grad_point then query should
    fetch 4.5 instead of 3 when we notify result for all 4 semester but
    when we notify for upto 2nd semester its could return 3
    grad_point.here i construct a sql which working fine in selection bt
    when i make it view then i got a problem for handling it different
    semester its always return max for 4th semester result bt in view
    its missed the course upto 2 semester gpa here is query

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.institution 
 ,A.acad_career 
 ,A.emplid 
 ,a.crse_id 
 ,A.UNT_TAKEN 
 , a.acad_prog 
 ,first_value(a.grade_points) OVER (PARTITION BY A.emplid 
 ,a.crse_id 
  ORDER BY a.grade_points DESC) AS GPA 
  ,first_value(a.strm) OVER (PARTITION BY A.emplid 
  ,a.crse_id 
  ORDER BY a.grade_points DESC) AS strm 
  FROM ps_qau_maxgp_ugrd a 
 WHERE acad_career='UGRD' 
 AND Emplid LIKE '04091313014%'
 AND Strm='1313'
  ORDER BY A.institution ,A.acad_career ,A.emplid  ,A.UNT_TAKEN , a.acad_prog
```

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Please post some sample data, actual output and expected output

Comment: I don't understand. You are selecting the highest grade an employee has received in a course over different sessions, and call that the "GPA"? Why? GPA has a very well defined meaning which is different from your choice. I don't see where the actual GPA is calculated, anywhere in your code. In addition to the code, you should show the table structure (table names, column names and data types and how they are related). You did a decent job of explaining the requirement, so it is not necessary to repeat it. Then please show a small sample of output so we know what you need.

Comment: Also, it seems what you are showing here is an intermediate result. If so, that's OK, but show us the desired FINAL result. It is entirely possible that this intermediate step is not needed, and you can get a simpler, faster solution that is easier to write, read and maintain.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to look at the date the grade was entered. For a given term and class-nbr, you should pull the greatest grade:
pseudo code:

```
select 
   max(date_entered) 
group by 
   institution, 
   acad_career,
   crse_id, 
   term,
   class_nbr(if you have it)
```

The problem is that with the table you are using, i don't beleive is the actual enrollment table. I am only familiar with CS, so i would be looking at the ps_stdnt_enrl table or the ps_stdnt_car_term to get the accumulated data for a term.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `MAX` and `GROUP BY`.

```
SELECT A.institution, 
       A.acad_career, 
       A.emplid, 
       a.crse_id, 
       A.unt_taken, 
       a.acad_prog, 
       Max(a.grade_points) GPA, 
       Max(a.strm)         AS strm 
FROM   ps_qau_maxgp_ugrd a 
WHERE  acad_career = 'UGRD' 
       AND emplid LIKE '04091313014%' 
       AND strm = '1313' 
GROUP  BY A.institution, 
          A.acad_career, 
          A.emplid, 
          a.crse_id, 
          A.unt_taken, 
          a.acad_prog;
```

Comment: sorry its does not work in reverse case if students obtained less marks in 4 semester then best is 2nd sem marks.

Comment: @saqib that's why I asked for sample data.

Comment: sing i add some of pic of sample data please look into respectively ...i need all of out in  one view bt my scripts working fine as individual bt after making a view its missed repeating course for 2nd semester

Comment: I don't see any image or link in the question. Better post the sample data as text.